# OpenZeppelin AccountAccess getRoleMemberCount not avaiable as a public function

Tags: openzeppelin

I'm trying to get the count of accounts that have a role. I'm not sure what more I need to do to make the public function getRoleMemberCount available to be called on the contract. Other examples I see in videos show that I only need to import the AccessControl.sol, but when I do that I dont have the functions that are listed in the IEnumberableAccessControl.sol.
There must be something super basic that I'm missing.
all I want to be able to do is after loading a contract, call this in my chia tests.

```
const { contract, owner } = await loadFixture(deployTokenFixture);
const minterRole = await contract.MINTER_ROLE();
const minterCount = await contract.getRoleMemberCount(minterRole);
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.1/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.1/access/AccessControl.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, AccessControl {

    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");

    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {
        _grantRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, AccessControl)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    
}
```

---

Here is an example of it working with an older version where openzeppelin is being referenced via a github url.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken2 is ERC20, AccessControl {

    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");

    constructor(address minter) public ERC20("MYTOKEN", "TKN") {
        _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, minter);
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Check the release branches of `/contracts/access`, upon v4.0 the `getRoleMemberCount` is not included anymore in `AccessControl`.

You can see this in the commit [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/commit/e341bdc1b741b8f21a73ffbdffad7cb5aaa0e9a2) where the `Changelog.md` also states:

`AccessControl: removed enumerability by default for a more lightweight contract. It is now opt-in through AccessControlEnumerable. ([#2512](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/2512))`

- AccessControl [release-v3.4.0](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol) with `getRoleMemberCount`
- AccessControl [release-v4.0](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v4.0/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol) without  `getRoleMemberCount`
- AccessControlEnumerable [release-v4.0](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v4.0/contracts/access/AccessControlEnumerable.sol) was added with v4.0 - its not available within the access contracts [release-v3.4.0](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/v3.4.0/contracts/access).
- The AccessControlEnumerable contains the `getRoleMemberCount`

From the v4.0 release:

```
interface IAccessControlEnumerable {
    function getRoleMember(bytes32 role, uint256 index) external view returns (address);
    function getRoleMemberCount(bytes32 role) external view returns (uint256);
}
```

Sample implementation with `AccessControlEnumerable`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControlEnumerable.sol";

contract MyToken is AccessControlEnumerable {
    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");

    constructor() {
        _grantRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I tried that and got an error saying something was already referenced. https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/IAccessControlEnumerable.sol also imports IAccessControl.sol.

I typed out the code from video I saw and it was working as expected. This example is referencing an older version and specifying via a url.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/IAccessControlEnumerable.sol

Comment: Here's the example of the working contract. 

```

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken2 is ERC20, AccessControl {

    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");

    constructor(address minter) public ERC20("MYTOKEN", "TKN") {
        _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, minter);
    }

}
```

Comment: @ScottBorchert I think this may be an issue because of different releases - v3.4.0 vs. v4.0. I updated my answer

Comment: When I call the function getMemberRoleCount and pass in the role, the transaction is being reverted. Message: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.

Comment: I found that when I log the address(this), its being logged a couple hundred times as if its being called that many times which seems weird. Maybe its a infinite loop and thats that the error message about payable really means?

Comment: was also struggling a bit now - I rewrote the code above to directly inherit the `AccessControlEnumerable`. Also add the `DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE` when you construct the contract. After that (if you use remix f.e.) deploy the contract, use the owner address to `grantRole` a custom role of type `bytes32` to another address, for example with this tool: https://web3-type-converter.onbrn.com/. And then create multiple members (as owner with `grantRole`) and afterwards check for their role with `getRoleMember` or their count by role with `getRoleMemberCount`. It worked for me in remix

Comment: Works! THANK YOU!!! I have to say I really learned a log working through this with you. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome! glad that it works for you